# Dead Ram Slot or not in dual channel?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a dual channel motherboard for my ram.I had two 4GB ram sticks attached to it.

Recently one of them have stopped functioning.I have troubleshooted the problem by individually checking the ram sticks. Both work fine when I insert them in channel B, but the the problem starts when my computer wont boot with channel A.

I want to know whether my ram slot is actually dead or is it just dust settling on the ram slot which is interfering with it as I seem to have a lot of dust stored in my case. 
Can anyone suggest a software which can tell me whether my ram slot is dead or not??. I have already tried speccy and it tells me I have a 1 free memory slot and 1 used slot.

Does it falsely report dead slot as a free memory slot.
Any thoughts, anyone??

Comment: Did you simply try to clean your case?

Comment: @Seth I haven't tried it,its the reason why I am asking if anyone knows about any software which can detect a dead ram slot. That way I'll know whether cleaning my case will do any good

Comment: Regardless of it, it will do your case good as it will bring down the temperature of your components. Especially if you clean your heatsinks. It's also the easiest way to figure out whenever dust is the problem. There is no software that will easily tell you what you want to know. The easiest check you can do you already dead, the slot doesn't work if you insert a module. If the module isn't detected by your BIOS something physical is odd. So go and clean your case. Check again if it's still not working assume it's broken.